# Use of 'swag' as a verb

Tags: verbs, word-usage

I came across this post on swag (the slang word):

> Attempt to swag should ideally be accompanied by apt spellings.

I have seen *swag* being used only as a noun. I know *swagger* is a verb, but is *swag* one, too?

Comment: It sounds either ungrammatical or contrived as it stands, Surviswa. Can we have a few more sentences? Looking up "swag meaning" in a Google search, one immediately finds two senses of 'swag' used as a verb.

Comment: No, there aren't any other examples to show.This came up on my Facebook wall.

Comment: Any noun at all — and indeed absolutely any *word* at all — can be used as a verb. Nothing prevents you from swagging, betweening, egadsing or greating. That's just how English works.

Answer (score 2):

I think that use of the word "swag" in that sentence is a slang abbreviation of the word "swagger" which is itself slang for "show off". So a rough translation would be "if you are going to show off in a post, you should at least attempt to use the right spelling [else it would undermine your swagger]".

Comment: Agreed, Marv. But is that allowed? If he meant swagger, he should've used that, right? Like I said, this appeared on my Facebook wall so don't rule out the possibility that it could be an ordinary typo.

He may have meant: "Attempt to [show] swag..."

Comment: @SurviswaReeve Unless your Facebook friend is really into "[festooning](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/festooning)", I recommend responding with a link to [Muphry's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muphry's_law) and maybe a snarky little winky face ;). (Note: this comment contains no misspellings: it's not *Murphy* we're talking about here.)

Comment: @SurviswaReeve: what do you mean, "allowed"? Allowed by whom? He did it, so obviously it's possible, and you understood him, so obviously it's fine.

Comment: @RegDwigнt It also made her (and possibly others) question her friend's "correctness", which may be undesirable for him, given that he, himself, appears to be correcting someone else's spelling (though he be mollified by the thought that he was, at least, understood).

Comment: @RegDwight I didn't understand how Surviswa's friend was using the word. Does that make it not fine?

Answer (score 0):

Most words in American English can be used as a verb in the right context. In addition, there are currently several Internet memes that specifically use words as the improper part of speech (e.g. the [Doge](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/doge) meme). The fact that this was on Facebook implies a casual environment, in which the slang word "swag" can be easily understood as a verb, roughly equivalent to any other verb used on this versatile word:

- "Attempt to drop the swag..."
- "Attempt to swag us up..."
- "Attempt to show the swag..."
- "Swagging attempt..."
- "Attempted swag wielding..."
- "Attempt to start the swag-mania..."

I believe these are all equally valid uses of the slang word "swag", and all essentially the same meaning as OP's quote.